# mysql workbench cannot : update where like

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-workbench, sql-like

Normally i can update my rows w/ queries such as

`UPDATE t SET col1='123' WHERE col2 LIKE '%abc%';`

or

`UPDATE mydb.t SET col1='123' WHERE col2 LIKE '%abc%';`

But with MySQL Workbench I seem to only be able to `SELECT` but cannot `UPDATE` the tables with queries.

Does anyone know a fix for working with workbench?

**FIX**

To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor and reconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql workbench usually disables by default updates without a where clause, and/or updates that hit more than a configured X elements.

When you try to update and fail, if it is how I think it is, then pay attention to the error message, as it tells you exactly which setting to change.

Comment: You can find the error details and answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231278/error-error-code-1175-during-executing-update-command-on-table-using-mysql-wo