# Error (Error Code: 1175) during executing update command on table using MySQL Workbench 5.2

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-workbench, error-code

I'm using MySQL Server5.5 in which MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE is included. I'm using MySQL Workbench 5.2 . I have a table named **user** in DB. I executed the following command on SQL Editor at MySQL Workbench:

```
UPDATE user SET email = 'abc@yahoo.com' WHERE email='ripon.wasim@yahoo.com';
```

But unfortunately I got the following error:

```
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor and reconnect.
```

What's the wrong? Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL error code: 1175 when updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-when-updating)

Comment: `user` is a reserved word, you probably also need to enclose it with backticks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: good suggestion though I did not face any problem in my case

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Every time you encountered that  kind of error when trying to update rows in mysql, It’s because you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a `KEY` column.

You can fix it using,

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE user SET email = 'abc@yahoo.com' WHERE email='ripon.wasim@yahoo.com';
```

or in the WorkBench

- Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Queries
- Uncheck Forbid UPDATE and DELETE statements without a WHERE clause (safe updates)
- Query --> Reconnect to Server

[image]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but `email` column has no key defined.

Comment: SQL_SAFE_UPDATES is a system variable, right? How can I get the list of system variable in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: in workbench 6.2 I didn't find "SQL Queries" instead found "SQL Editor"

Answer (score 3):

It is more correct to deactivate and reactivate

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0; --disable
UPDATE user SET email = 'abc@yahoo.com' WHERE email='ripon.wasim@yahoo.com';
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1; --enable
```