# Replace Existing String with New In MySql Table

Tags: mysql, replace

I have table like this :

[image]

In that `order_address` field is there.

In that I have stored details of buyer / user i.e. Name + address + City + Pin /Zip Code + State + Country + mobile.

Between All that I have used `sep` as separator of each one.
Now I want to replace all `sep` with some other character in whole table.

Suppose I want to replace `sep` with `//` in whole table.

So how to do that using query? I don't know about it so any suggestion for that.

Comment: Just a comment - why to use MySQL if it's commercially super expensive? Now I moved to JavaDB - also the syntax is a little bit different..

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis - Okay good idea, will follow from next project. But any suggestion for above query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Mysql [string](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-find-replace-text/) [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

Set [SQL_SAFE_UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231278/error-error-code-1175-during-executing-update-command-on-table-using-mysql-wo) mode

```
Update order_table 
set order_address = REPLACE(order_address , 'sep', '//')
WHERE order_address LIKE '%sep%';
```

Comment: Shall I have to use `WHERE order_address LIKE '%sep%'` compulsory or not ?

Comment: "You don't necessarily have to add the WHERE LIKE clause at the end, because if the text to find isn't there the row won't be updated, but it should speed things up." –  gmaggio

Comment: If i ll use above query it gives me an error `12:05:29 Update b2b.order_master set order_address = REPLACE(order_address , 'sep', '//') WHERE order_address LIKE '%sep%' Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect. 0.046 sec`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231278/error-error-code-1175-during-executing-update-command-on-table-using-mysql-wo

Comment: Whooa, great sir.. Query Solved. Thank You Praveen Sir. I have just Used set query your then update, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace), like this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET order_address = REPLACE (order_address, 'sep', '//')
WHERE order_address LIKE '%sep%'
```

Comment: Shall I have to use `WHERE order_address LIKE '%sep%'` compulsory or not ?

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ no, not compulsory. May improve the performance though.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473829/replace-existing-string-with-new-in-mysql-table?noredirect=1#comment32409977_21473829