# Why does MySQL think that I'm not using a WHERE statement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to update a table called `rep` in a database called `premier_products`. The table's primary key is `rep_num`.

When I run the following statement:

```
update rep 
set last_name = "Perry"
where rep_num = 85;
```

I get an error that says "You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column."

I Googled that error message and most of the responses were along the lines of "You have to use a `where` clause or turn off safe mode". But as you can see, I *am* using a `where` clause. Why is the error appearing if I have a `where` clause?

MySQL server version 5.6.20.

This image shows that rep_num is definitely my primary key:
[image]

This image shows the current rep table:
[image]

Comment: `rep_num` is prob not indexed. Either give it one or change your settings in workbench to remove that restriction.

Comment: You sure `rep_num` is a primary key? What does your table creation script look like?

Comment: @John - What do you mean by not indexed? Here's a picture of the table, if it helps: http://i.imgur.com/TSyZ6AX.png

Comment: @Pikamander2: That's its data. What is its structure?

Comment: Here is the script that was used to create it, if that's what you're asking: http://i.imgur.com/pKqVUD8.png

Comment: That's ... strange. MySQL server version?

Comment: Yeah, and if you look at this (http://i.imgur.com/xbuICZ6.png), it appears that rep_num is still the primary key.

Comment: MySQL Workbench is version 6.1.7.11891 build 1788.

Comment: @Pikamander2: No, MySQL _server_.

Comment: MySQL is version 5.6.20

Comment: Possibly, but probably not, related: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70472

Comment: `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;`, found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231278/error-error-code-1175-during-executing-update-command-on-table-using-mysql-wo#answer-14231331)

Comment: @skobaljic- I know how to make the message go away, but I want to know why it's appearing in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you save only numbers, your primary-key type is char(2) and not tinyint(2) and when you update the record you are giving **numerical** value instead **char** value in your where condition. I think thats where the indexing mechanism triggers the error and tells you, your where condition is unsafe or might yield wrong results.

in your case try

```
update rep 
set last_name = "Perry"
where rep_num = '85';
```

PS: why don't you name your tables with a prefix? like tbl_rep? just a thought.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. It's part of a homework assignment, so I have no control over the names.